# Gulp `serve:before` tasks not running in Ionic CLI v 3

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, ionic2, ionic3

Gulp `serve:before` tasks are not running in the Ionic CLI v3. They used to run well in Ionic CLI 2 and Ionic CLI 1.

`gulp.task('serve:before', ['watch']);`

This is the task. My app uses Ionic 1 and I did the necessary configurations and it is running well on Ionic CLI 3 upon `ionic serve` but not the gulp task `serve:before` is not running.

Comment: This is not a feature yet in Ionic 3, follow [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1989) issue for updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can update your code from:

```
gulp.task('serve:before', ['watch'])
```

to

```
gulp.task('ionic:watch:before', ['watch'])
```

If you install the ionic gulp plugin [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/tree/master/packages/cli-plugin-gulp).

My task also had a 'default' task, which can just be included alongside the watch task as before, so mine currently looks like this:

```
gulp.task('ionic:watch:before', ['default', 'watch'])
```

The weird thing is that it does not show any of the code being compiled on startup as it used to, but it does seem to actually do this.

=======================================

## Update for ionic CLI 4

I had to update the task name to the following in ionic cli 4:

```
gulp.task('ionic:serve:before', ['default', 'watch'])
```

Comment: As of CLI v3.8.0, the Ionic Gulp plugin is a part of core Ionic CLI and the integration [should be automatic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/README.md#integrations).

It's also worth noting that `ionic:watch:before` task is called when watch is needed, e.g. when using `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova run -l`. It is **not** called when using `ionic cordova run` without livereload. 

Similarly, `ionic:build:before` is called when `ionic cordova run` is used without livereload, or also on `ionic build`. More info [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli#cli-hooks)

Comment: Thanks @Arx. Unfortunately I see this change has broken it again, in that it has stopped running gulp, so will have to see what I need to change now.

Comment: @Arx - turns out the reason it stopped working for me was because gulp in package.json was specified under dependencies instead of under devDepenedencies. It now works like a charm. But the change from serve:before to ionic:watch:before will still need to be made if someone is upgrading from an older version of the ionic cli.

Comment: Where do you implement this custom gulp task on ionic 3? I would like to write a task to build for both android and iPhone at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: @GeraldBrigen - in your gulp file?